# How to tell if a customer's default payment source is a bank or card in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

My customers use the Stripe Customer portal to enter their default payment method, which can be a card or bank account. I'm having trouble figuring out which one they chose. I'm using the api.stripe.com/v1/customers API and the "default_source" object will return a card when the payment method is a card but when it is a bank I'm getting null. I just need to know whether they are using card or bank account so I can get the workflow going from there

Call looks like this:
`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_Ia2m9sl1Na1j1E -u sk_test_51Hx2pbGbd.. -d expand[] default_source  -d expand[] sources  -d expand[] subscriptions`

Answer (score 0):

You can [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/retrieve?lang=curl#retrieve_source) the `Source` object. Its [type](https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/object?lang=curl#source_object-type) tells you what kind of payment method this source object represents.

Comment: Seems like whether I retrieve the source or the default_method from the customers API I always get a blank value. It only works when the customer uses a card